# MongoDB 3.0.4 $nearSphere $maxDistance strange behaviour

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about distance measuring in a $maxDistance. I have document:

```
{
    "location": {
        { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 38.8993487, -77.0145665 ] }
    }
}
```

Making a query in a shell:

```
db.places.find({"location": {"$nearSphere": {"$geometry": {"type":"Point", "coordinates": [38.888684, -77.0047189]}, "$maxDistance": 1129 } }})[0].location
```

Returns a

```
{ "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 38.8993487, -77.0145665 ] }
```

But distance measurement made by [gpsvisualizer.com](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map?format=google&units=metric&lat1=38.8993487&lon1=-77.0145665&lat2=38.888684&lon2=-77.0047189&convert_format=&gc_segments=&gc_altitude=&tickmark_interval=&show_wpt=3&add_elevation=&trk_colorize=track) shows me **1.4600 km**. Mongo have a result with maxDistance set to **[1129 meters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/)**

So my question is - what did I miss ?:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missing the fact that mongoDB’s 2d spherical index operators only recognize [longitude, latitude] ordering. Correct link would be: [gpsvisualiser](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map?format=google&units=metric&lat1=-77.0145665&lon1=38.8993487&lat2=-77.0047189&lon2=38.888684&convert_format=&gc_segments=&gc_altitude=&tickmark_interval=&show_wpt=3&add_elevation=&trk_colorize=track). As you can see, distance between those points is about 1,13km :)

Comment: oh, thanks :D I was stuck on this for a couple hours :D